# Cucumber reporting only for failed tests

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am using [cucumber reporting tool](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting) to generate the cucumber reports, is it possible to configure the plugin in such a way so that it only show report of only the failed tests?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried editing the json files, bevore handing them over to the reporting tool?

Comment: No, I am just using the reporting tool plugin on Jenkins to generate the reports

Comment: @tintin How did you achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for viewing failed only filter. You would expect that when you click on the failed portion of charts or columns, it displays only failed tests. However that feature doesn't seem to exists. You may raise a request for this feature in their github support?

Alternatively, if you opt to use default junit report plugin in jenkins, it has the option to filter by failed or passed tests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure in Maven or Gradle. What you are using ?

Comment: I am using Gradle. How can I configure it to show the report of only failed tests?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html You need to use exclude and use pattern, It will regular expression to find out failure test from json and exclude from list.